# Eclipse Juno SR2 does not pick up certificate

Tags: java, eclipse, ssl, tfs, eclipse-juno

I downloaded the latest Eclipse Juno CDT SR2 release and now try to run it with MS TFS plugin for a server that requires SSL certificate on https connection. In Indigo it worked fine. I use the same settings copied from indigo/eclipse.ini, including all -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore= related stuff, however TFS plugin does not see the certificate and fails with 403 error when I connect, in -Djavax.net.debug=all I see "**the page requires a client certificate as part of the authentication process**" in the server's response.

Now I also see that in indigo's debug.all output there's

```
found key for : le-user-51c64ee7-2b5c-4714-a0c7-97c473a36784
```

at the very beginning of the debug log, while in juno's log it is absent. The le-user key is my certificate imported into the java's keystore that I pass via Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore in eclipse.ini.

Is it java problem, Juno problem, TFS problem, or my problem in that I do not understand something about these 3 guys? Seems like Juno does not pick up my certificate, why?

UPDATE: OK I reinstalled my pfx certificate and now it is loaded fine according to ssl log. But TFS still can't connect with same error message, while old TFS works fine in new Juno SR2 so it's clearly TFS problem.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/0c4d25f0-9b7a-4828-9cf2-b9a71d79da71/ sheds some light on the process, but without a clear answer.